# Intellij не импортирует метод

Tags: java, spring, maven

Создан класс WebConfig

```
package com.blog.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        freeMarkerViewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        return freeMarkerViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreeMarkerConfigurer() {
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("/", "WEB-INF/views");
        return freeMarkerConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Все библиотеки импортировано..

Также добавлены необходимые зависимости в pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
  <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.30</version>
</dependency>
```

Вопрос!

В классе WebConfig перечеркнуто наслдование от класса ***WebMvcConfigurerAdapter***

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

Я так понимаю этот класс устарел.. как можно узнать на какой более актуальный его можно заменить правильно?

и метод ***setTemplateLoaderPaths*** в коде:

`freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPaths("/", "WEB-INF/views");`

подсвечиваеться красным, тоесть не импортируеться. Может ли это быть изза того что я использую наследование от устаревшего класса (перечеркнуто).. или в чем то другом проблема, может я еще какие то зависимости не добавил..
Спасибо за помощь!

---

Вопрос не решен...есть еще варианты?

Comment: Возможно вам какой-то зависимости не хватает.

Может быть такой: `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>`

Comment: не помогло.. может есть какие то другие варианты? или как реализовать подобный метод..

Comment: К сожалению больше ничем помочь не могу. Maven не использую и HTML только через Angular делаю. Других идей у меня по вашей проблеме нет.

Comment: может стоит на gradle пробовать?

Comment: Вряд ли это исправит проблему. Пока что, мне кажется, выглядит всё как проблема в версиях зависимостей. Т.е. вы используете код, который должен работать на старых версиях библиотек, а подключаете новую. Возможно, в документации к либе что-то на этот счёт сказано.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй заменить `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` на `WebMvcConfigurer`

Comment: Заменил, но метод setTemplateLoaderPaths все ровно подсвечивает красным, может его можно заменить на какой то аналогичный?